# how to create react router doom new version

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to create new version react-router and set up my computer
Showing error code 404 when creating

maybe this issue is because the new version of the react-router have few days,

I am using the last version of the react-router and I want to do the routing through

Answer (score 0):

if  you are   facing  issues  with  new  version  ,read  this  documentation it   will  help

[https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview][1]